# Get the dictionary on a list where there is a specific key value pairs

Tags: python, json, list, dictionary

Assuming i have this dictionary inside a list:

```
 [
    {
        "Name": "Person",
        "Confidence": 97.56156921386719,
        "Instances": [
            {
                "BoundingBox": {
                    "Width": 0.6137702465057373,
                    "Height": 0.9175498485565186,
                    "Left": 0.22297996282577515,
                    "Top": 0.0739903450012207
                },
                "Confidence": 94.51961517333984
            },
            {
                "BoundingBox": {
                    "Width": 0.46570318937301636,
                    "Height": 0.6405649781227112,
                    "Left": 0.11447866261005402,
                    "Top": 0.34079012274742126
                },
                "Confidence": 82.2153549194336
            }
        ],
        "Parents": []
    },
    {
        "Name": "Human",
        "Confidence": 97.56156921386719,
        "Instances": [],
        "Parents": []
    },
    {
        "Name": "Clothing",
        "Confidence": 91.08417510986328,
        "Instances": [],
        "Parents": []
    }
    }]
```

How can I retrieve the dictionary with key value *"Name":"Clothing"* only? is it possible to retrieve it from the dictionary? The Key *"Clothing"* may appear in any part of the list.

```
    {
        "Name": "Clothing",
        "Confidence": 91.08417510986328,
        "Instances": [],
        "Parents": []
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `.get(Key, defaultValue)` can be used here.

`.get("Name", "")` --> Returns an empty string if the key `Name` doesn't exist in the dictionary. [doc](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.get)
`.get("Name")` --> Returns `None` if `Name` doesn't exist.

So `.get("Name") == "Clothing"` is the criteria for selection of a dictionary.

And use [filter()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#filter) to choose only those that satisfy the criteria.

Putting it all together

```
filter(lambda x: x.get("Name") == "Clothing", mylist)
```

filter returns an iterator, so you could pass that to list to create a full list.
If you just want to iterate over it, no need to call list.

So,

```
list(filter(lambda x: x.get("Name") == "Clothing", mylist))
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following code to get every item that has `Name` of `Clothing`:

```py
names = [
    {
        "Name": "Person",
        "Confidence": 97.56156921386719,
        "Instances": [
            {
                "BoundingBox": {
                    "Width": 0.6137702465057373,
                    "Height": 0.9175498485565186,
                    "Left": 0.22297996282577515,
                    "Top": 0.0739903450012207
                },
                "Confidence": 94.51961517333984
            },
            {
                "BoundingBox": {
                    "Width": 0.46570318937301636,
                    "Height": 0.6405649781227112,
                    "Left": 0.11447866261005402,
                    "Top": 0.34079012274742126
                },
                "Confidence": 82.2153549194336
            }
        ],
        "Parents": []
    },
    {
        "Name": "Human",
        "Confidence": 97.56156921386719,
        "Instances": [],
        "Parents": []
    },
    {
        "Name": "Clothing",
        "Confidence": 91.08417510986328,
        "Instances": [],
        "Parents": []
    }
]

for name in names:
    if name['Name'] == 'Clothing':
        print(name)
```

If you want it to be short you can use the following code:

```py
x = [y for y in names if name['Name'] == 'Clothing']
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this simple `list comprehension`:

```
[print(dictionary) for dictionary in lst if 'Name' in dictionary.keys() and dictionary['Name'] == 'Clothing']
```

Output:

```
{'Name': 'Clothing', 'Confidence': 91.08417510986328, 'Instances': [], 'Parents': []}
```

Here is the full code:

```
lst =  [
    {
        "Name": "Person",
        "Confidence": 97.56156921386719,
        "Instances": [
            {
                "BoundingBox": {
                    "Width": 0.6137702465057373,
                    "Height": 0.9175498485565186,
                    "Left": 0.22297996282577515,
                    "Top": 0.0739903450012207
                },
                "Confidence": 94.51961517333984
            },
            {
                "BoundingBox": {
                    "Width": 0.46570318937301636,
                    "Height": 0.6405649781227112,
                    "Left": 0.11447866261005402,
                    "Top": 0.34079012274742126
                },
                "Confidence": 82.2153549194336
            }
        ],
        "Parents": []
    },
    {
        "Name": "Human",
        "Confidence": 97.56156921386719,
        "Instances": [],
        "Parents": []
    },
    {
        "Name": "Clothing",
        "Confidence": 91.08417510986328,
        "Instances": [],
        "Parents": []
    }
]

[print(dictionary) for dictionary in lst if 'Name' in dictionary.keys() and dictionary['Name'] == 'Clothing']
```

Comment: any pythonic style for this? or its better this way?

Comment: You can use a list comprehension as I have mentioned above. List comprehensions are more pythonic

Comment: I wouldn't print in the list  comprehension, but a list comprehension is the typical way to filter a list.

Comment: Yeah...I agree. But is printing elements in a list comprehension a not-so-good way to code?

Comment: To that downvoter: Can u pls explain what is wrong with my code?

Comment: I upvoted; one slight change I would make is to replace the condition in list comprehension with `dictionary.get("Name") == "Clothing"`.

Comment: Oh...And the reason behind it? Both `dictionary['Name'] == "Clothing"` and `dictionary.get("Name") == "Clothing"` do the same. Why would u prefer the second one? BTW, thx for upvoting!!!

Comment: @Sushil using `get` you can drop the `"Name" in dictionary.keys()` check, since `dictionary.get("Name")` will automatically return `None` if `"Name"` is not a key.

Answer (score -1):

Assuming your list is called `my_list`, then this should give you what you want:

`my_list_new = [x for x in my_list if ("Name", "Clothing") in x.items()]`

Comment: will be marked this as answer in  after a few minutes, I choose this one as this is shorter than the earlier answer

Comment: Downvoted. `if ("Name", "Clothing") in x.items()` is unnecessarily inefficient and unreadable. It's ignoring the whole point of using a dict.

Comment: @blhsing agreed. For those wondering why it is inefficient. This list comprehension has to call `x.items()` for every dictionary x in my_list. And it linear searches for the tuple ("Name", "Clothing") on each of those results. For all the dictionaries that don't have that tuple, it would read every single key,value pair to choose not to include x.

Comment: i see. Thanks for the feedback